Why Webgl give a warning when gl.useProgram is not invoked when setting the uniform
My code works fine if I invoke gl.useProgram at the very beginning. On the other hand, If I never invoke gl.useProgram, nothing displayed and get two kind of waring in the console:
First:
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: uniformMatrix4fv: location is not from current program

Second:
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawElements: no valid shader program in use

The second warning makes sense to me, here is the signature for drawElements
drawElements(mode: GLenum, count: GLsizei, type: GLenum, offset: GLintptr):

When you issue a draw call, you need to know which program to run but the call signature has no hint for program, so a global program is necessary, so I put gl.useProgram just before gl.drawElements and everything works fine, but the first kind of warning persists which makes no sense to me! let see the signature for set Uniform
vertexAttrib4fv(index: GLuint, values: Iterable<GLfloat>): void;

the first is effectively an address in memory the program can refer to at the runtime and the address should be got from the program like
getUniformLocation(program: WebGLProgram, name: string): WebGLUniformLocation | null;

The program is already used to get the address, why the current global state is necessary when setting the uniform? Is there any kind of case I missed which does cause a problem?


the first is effectively an address in memory the program can refer to at the runtime and the address should be got from the program like

No it's not, uniform locations are zero based indices within a linked program, the GPU driver handles the memory mapping.
If you were to use a less safe language like C you could set the first uniform of whatever is the currently active program by calling glUniform1f(0, val) and the second using glUniform1f(1,val) and so on, however different vendors use different enumeration strategies, so without using more recent GLSL versions that support layout location qualifiers there's no guarantee the first uniform declaration appearing in your shader code is actually assigned index 0.
